# How to read BigQuery table using python pipeline code in GCP Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-platform

Could someone please  share syntax to read/write bigquery table in a pipeline written in python for GCP Dataflow

Answer (score 10):

**Run on Dataflow**

First, construct a `Pipeline` with the following options for it to run on GCP DataFlow:

```
import apache_beam as beam

options = {'project': <project>,
           'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
           'region': <region>,
           'setup_file': <setup.py file>}
pipeline_options = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options = pipeline_options)
```

**Read from BigQuery**

Define a `BigQuerySource` with your query and use `beam.io.Read` to read data from BQ:

```
BQ_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query = <query>)
BQ_data = pipeline | beam.io.Read(BQ_source)
```

**Write to BigQuery**

There are two options to write to bigquery:

- use a `BigQuerySink` and `beam.io.Write`:

  ```
  BQ_sink = beam.io.BigQuerySink(<table>, dataset=<dataset>, project=<project>)
  BQ_data | beam.io.Write(BQ_sink)
  ```
- use `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`:

  ```
  BQ_data | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(<table>, dataset=<dataset>, project=<project>)
  ```

Comment: Thanks Robbe for the response..But I need to use Google auth Json file to connect to Bigquery tables which i have created.Could you please point out the modifications that need to be made in the above code to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean a service account? [When running a pipeline on dataflow, it is automatically connected to the dataflow service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#dataflow-service-account). You can alter the permissions of this service account in the Cloud Console.

Comment: I just started dataflow,Could you helpout with the below :

I executed Python file with below code on Cloudshell

Comment: Getting Error:
No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StackOverflow_B.py", line 12, in <module>
    BQ_sink = beam.io.BigQuerySink(CustomerDetails_copy, dataset=StarPoc, project=star-poc)
NameError: name 'CustomerDetails_copy' is not defined

Comment: If possible could you please share a small complete working code with some sample values for the "Query" ,"table name" values filled out

Comment: The [_Error: No handlers could be found for logger "oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file"_ is a harmles bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK/issues/34).
You're getting a NameError because you are supplying a variable _CustomerDetails_copy_, which is not defined. Try supplying the name of your BQ-table as a string instead.
You can find documentation about the expected arguments [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L446)

Comment: Providing small snippet of code i am executing:     BQ_source = beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='SELECT * FROM star-poc.StarPoc.CustomerDetails')
BQ_data = pipeline | beam.io.Read(BQ_source)
BQ_data | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery("CustomerDetails_copy", dataset="StarPoc", project="star-poc")  .But getting error

Comment: (fe5999326acca3b7): Workflow failed. Causes: (fe5999326acca83f): 
S01:Read+WriteToBigQuery/WriteToBigQuery/NativeWrite failed., (da52e168e1918698): BigQuery execution failed., (da52e168e19189c9): 
Error: Message: Invalid table name: `star-poc:StarPoc.CustomerDetails` [Try using standard SQL

Comment: Runner is not able to read the source table.I have provided all the permissions that might be required to access the table.Could you please suggest what might be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Reading from Bigquery

```
rows = (p | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=QUERY, use_standard_sql=True))
```

writing to Bigquery

```
rows | 'writeToBQ' >> beam.io.Write(
beam.io.BigQuerySink('{}:{}.{}'.format(PROJECT, BQ_DATASET_ID, BQ_TEST), schema='CONVERSATION:STRING, LEAD_ID:INTEGER', create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import StaticValueProvider

# Set the necessary pipeline options, such as project and job name
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    project='your-project-id',
    job_name='dataflow-job',
    staging_location='gs://your-bucket/staging',
    temp_location='gs://your-bucket/temp',
    runner='DataflowRunner'
)

# Create a pipeline object using the options
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

# Define a function to read data from BigQuery
def read_from_bigquery():
    return (p
            | 'Read from BigQuery' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                query='SELECT * FROM `your-project-id.your-dataset.source_table`',
                use_standard_sql=True)
            )

# Define a function to write data to BigQuery
def write_to_bigquery(data):
    return (data
            | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table='your-project-id.your-dataset.target_table',
                schema='column_1:string,column_2:integer,column_3:boolean',
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
            )

# Define your data processing logic
data = (p
        | 'Read Data' >> beam.Create(['dummy'])  # Create a dummy input element
        | 'Trigger Read' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: read_from_bigquery())
        | 'Process Data' >> beam.Map(lambda row: (row['column_1'], row['column_2'], row['column_3']))
        )

# Write the processed data to BigQuery
write_to_bigquery(data)

# Run the pipeline
p.run()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).