# What are the differences between `WriteToBigQuery` and `BigQuerySink`

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399833/7598113) I wonder what are the principal differences (if any) between `WriteToBigQuery` and `BigQuerySink` of the Apache Beam Python SDK.

What are the considerations or limitations of using one over another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking [at sources](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3a182d64c86ad038692800f5c343659ab0b935b0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L471):

> BigQuerySink triggers a Dataflow native sink for BigQuery 
>   that only supports batch pipelines. Instead of using this sink
>   directly, please use WriteToBigQuery transform that works for both
>   batch and streaming pipelines.

They both seem to do a [similar](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3a182d64c86ad038692800f5c343659ab0b935b0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L775) [thing](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/3a182d64c86ad038692800f5c343659ab0b935b0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1369) underneath otherwise.

Comment: I have stumbled once on the “Cloud Pub/Sub is currently available for use only in streaming pipelines” exception in the “dataflow_runner”. If a `BigQuerySink` cannot be used for the streaming pipelines then I believe it should be addressed similarly to Pub/Sub usage.

Comment: Confirming that using `BigQuerySink` within the streaming mode and Dataflow runner will fail pipeline with “Workflow failed. Causes: Unknown streaming sink: big query” error on data flow pipeline job page and with an exception: “AssertionError: Job did not reach a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.” in a stack trace.